# Why is the warning about find important?

Tags: linux, find

I'm reading how Linux works by Brian Ward and he has issued the following warning "Don't try options such as -exec before you know this form by heart"
`find -name file -print`

Thus far, I have not understood why that form in particular is so important. Why might I not want to search for directories in a particular place regardless of their name. Also, it seems to me that -print is a default option and the manpage strongly suggests using -print0 as some file names may include new line characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The author cautions the reader against trying `-exec` without understanding the structure and approach of the `find` command.

There is no harm in you trying `find -type d -print`, for example. **CAUTION** But do you understand what would happen if you ran this `find -depth -type d -exec mv {} {}.surprise \;`?

If you want to see what would happen, replace (or supplement) the `mv` with a command that performs no permanent action:

```
find -depth -type d -exec echo mv {} {}.surprise \;
```

With regard to `-print0`, that is only of use when working within a pipeline. (But it's very useful there when your other utilities support its NUL-separated records.) If you want simply to list the `find` output for visual inspection, use `-print` instead.

---

PS. When you want to recover from having run the dangerous command on an important part of your filesystem you can *probably* run `find -depth -type d -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' d; do mv "$d" "${d%.surprise}"; done`. But it would have been better to try it in a safe part of `/tmp`.